# skip a section of programming

Tags: python, authentication

I am trying to program a sort of login system as part of my computing course. While programming this I came across the issue that when I input my username as "j.smith" it asks for a username again. I think that it should just skip straight to the password check. Any advice or notifications of errors is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
#SETTING VARIABLES
user_name = "l.parker"
password = "Password1"
user_name_2 = "j.smith"
password2 = "Password2"
user = "user0"

#USERNAME CHECK
if input("What is your username?") == user_name:
    print("Hello Luke")
    user == "user1"   
elif input("What is your username?") == user_name_2:
    print("Hello John")
    user == "user2"
else:
    print("That's not right")
    quit()

#PASSWORD CHECK
if user == "user1":
    if input("What is your password?") == password:
        print("You have successfully logged in")
    else:
        print("That's not right")
        quit()
elif user == "user2":
    if input("What is your password?") == password2:
        print("You have successfully logged in")
    else:
        print("That's not right")
        quit()
```

Comment: As a side note, you could improve this quite a bit by lists of usernames, real names, and passwords, instead of having to duplicate all your code twice and switch on "user1" vs. "user2". Or, even better, a dictionary that maps usernames to real names and passwords. But if you haven't learned those things yet, don't worry about it.

Comment: I haven't learned about this yet but I'll be sure to ask about it now that its been brought to my attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *accidentally* using comparison operator (`==`) instead of assign operator (`=`) on this line:

```
user == "user1"   
# Should be:
user = "user1"
```

Plus you are calling input multiple times (already [pointed out by popovitsj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26432109/1149736)).

But much more scalable solution would be to encapsulate user into object and store multiple users in list, like:

```
class User(object):

    def __init__(self, username, password, common_name=None):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.common_name = common_name

users = [
    User('l.parker', 'Password1', 'Luke'),
    User('j.smith', 'Password2', 'John')
]

name = input('What is your username? ')

# Fetch user
user = None
for u in users:
    if u.username == name:
       user = u
       break

# Any user matched?
if user is None:
    print('That\'s not right')
    quit()

password = input('What is your password? ')

# Password
if user.password != password
    print('That\'s not right')
    quit()

print('Dear {}, you have successfully logged in!'.format(user.common_name))
```

Comment: If you're going to go with a `User` class and a list of users (both things the OP hasn't learned about yet, but it's never too early to learn), why not go with a dict mapping usernames to `User` objects instead, which would be even more idiomatic (and concise, simple, efficient, etc.)?

Comment: @abarnert I thought about it but it felt like saying to build a table with only one index on one column (user name). *And what if he wants to list all users based on name* - that kind of stuff. Anyway I'm no longer satisfied with my answer and I think user should accept [three_pineables' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26435184/1149736) (and any edit on my side would be attempt to get closer to his, more explanatory answer)

Comment: I think your answer at least solves the problem and adds some useful info. Especially since the OP has said that he wants to learn about loops and lists and dictionaries and is going to ask his professor about them, having an example of how they can simplify things and/or make them more flexible is probably pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

You're combining two things on 1 row: getting user input and checking if it matches a username. That makes it hard to check it for multiple user names. To solve this, split it up by putting the user input into a variable and checking against that.

```
name = input("What is your username?")

if name == user_name_1:
    print("Hello Luke")
    user = "user1"   
elif name == user_name_2:
    print("Hello John")
    user = "user2"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and is simple enough to understand and repeat!

Answer (score 1):

While this answer is effectively rehashing the other answers here, I don't feel that either of those have actually explained to you why your code is behaving the way it is.

Let's take a look at this bit of code:

```
if input("What is your username?") == user_name:
    print("Hello Luke")
    user == "user1"   
elif input("What is your username?") == user_name_2:
    print("Hello John")
    user == "user2"
else:
    print("That's not right")
    quit()
```

What does the first line do?

```
if input("What is your username?") == user_name:
```

If compares the result of user input to the contents of the variable `user_name`.
The execution is as follows:

1. Python executes the input function, prompting the user
2. The user enters some text
3. This text is returned by the `input()` call and compared to `user_name`
4. It doesn't match, so we move on

So it moves to the next condition:

```
elif input("What is your username?") == user_name_2:
```

Again, the same sequence of events as before happens, which includes prompting the user for their username again.

This is why you see the prompt twice, because you have asked Python to prompt the user over and over again for every condition you check until it finds a match.

The solution (as pointed out by the other people who have answered) is to only ask the question once, store that, and then do the comparisons. See the answer by [popovitsj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26432109/1994235).

While it might be tempting to use [Vyktor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26432287/1994235)'s answer in it's entirety, I would caution you against copy/pasting large chunks of code of stackoverflow and using them in your assignments. This is likely to get you in trouble (tutors/lecturers are not idiots - I speak from the experience of being a tutor)  and it only takes 5 seconds of googling to prove that a student blindly took a complete rewrite of their code from stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me to get my head around the other answers

Comment: @LukeParker Not a problem. Now that you have an answer, it's customary to select the green tick next to one answer you consider the best of all posted (so whichever of the three posted here) and to upvote any others you found helpful.